# Subquery split comma separated value into two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I have a field that sometimes has one value and sometimes 2 values separated by a comma.I need to split the values into two columns. I have seen solutions using functions, but i need to add it to a view.

Here is what I have been trying to do for the first column

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT reportto FROM dbo.placement WHERE reportto like '%,%') 
THEN
(Select Substring(reportTo, 1,Charindex(',', reportTo)-1) as [Primary OTS Approver]
from placement) 
ELSE (SELECT reportto as [Primary OTS Approver] FROM dbo.placement)
END
```

Comment: Search here for "parse delimited string".  This has been asked a million times.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subselects in your `CASE` statemant, you can work with the columns directly:

```
SELECT
      CASE
         WHEN CHARINDEX(',', reportto) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(reportto, 1, CHARINDEX(',', reportto) -1)
         ELSE reportto
      END AS  [Primary OTS Approver]
   FROM
      placement;
```

Comment: I'd change the `like` to `charindex(',', reportto)>0`

Comment: @SqlZim I used `LIKE` because the OP did. But you are right - I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: This works on its own, but when I add it to the view I get an error "subquery returned more than one value"

Comment: @stvnmil Without knowing the rest of your view I can only guess that a `JOIN` is probably better suited than a subselect

Answer (score 0):

You can use CROSS APPLY to reduce the code complexity and simplify your main SELECT statement

With this example you only need to call CHARINDEX once and reuse it as value "P"

```
DROP TABLE #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ID INT, Vals CHAR(100))

INSERT INTO  #TMP(VALS)
VALUES
('32')
,('31,25')
,('21,32')

SELECT
    CASE    
        WHEN P > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(VALS, 1, P -1) 
        ELSE VALS 
        END AS  [Primary OTS Approver]
FROM
    #TMP
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',',VALS,0) P) Z
```